# Sql query to check 3 consecutive values are present in DB or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query DB to check if 3 values (ex: us, uk, usr) are present in DB field , if present it should return true if not it has to return the value which is not present.

```
Select  ( case  when  exists ( select Detail
                               from Application
                               where EmpID = '123' and Detail = ?
                              )
                then 1  
                else 0  
           end )
```

The result should return such = US (which is not present in DB)
[image]

Comment: Please add a reasonably-sized sample table with data which explains your problem.

Comment: Why would a `CASE` expression that returns `1` or `0` return `'US'`?

Comment: IF US is present in table query should return true or it should return the value which is not present. NOTE - i will passing the all 3 values as parameter

Comment: Then you'll need to add `AND Detail = 'US'` to the `WHERE`. Your current query checks for the existence of any row with `EmpID` 123.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  ( case  when  exists ( select Detail
                                   from Application
                                   where EmpID = '123' and Detail IN ('us', 'uk', 'usr')
                                  )
                    then 1  
                    else 0  
               end )
```

**EDIT**

> is there anyway to return the value which is not present in the table
>   instead of 0 or 1(eg: US) – ?

```
select case when Detail IN ('us', 'uk', 'usr')
            then Detail
            else '-'
        end
from Application
where EmpID = '123'
```

**EDIT 2**

> However it returns value which is present in DB, how can i modify it
>   to return the values which are not in DB?

```
Select  ( case  when  exists ( select Detail
                               from Application
                               where EmpID = '123'
                              )
                then (select case when Detail IN ('us', 'uk', 'usr')
                                  then Detail
                                  else '-'
                             end
                      from Application
                      where EmpID = '123' 
                      )
                else '-'  
           end )
```

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to return the value which is not present in the table instead of 0 or 1(eg: US)

Comment: Tried and working, thanks. However it returns value which is present in DB, how can i modify it to return the values which are not in DB?

Comment: Try it this way, it's a cross between my solution and your initial query